# Как правильно передать в foreach вывод постов (на примере WP_Query)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть вывод постов при помощи `WP_Query`:

```
while ( $query_select_today->have_posts() ) : 
    $count++;
    $query_select_today->the_post();
    include locate_template( 'include/vlog-news.php' );
endwhile;
```

Я хочу сделать аналогичный вывод постов с помощью `foreach`.

```
  global $wpdb;
  $msg = '';
  if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    $page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page']);
    $cur_page = $page;
    $page -= 1;
    $per_page = 10;
    $previous_btn = true;
    $next_btn = true;
    $start = $page * $per_page;
    // Set the table where we will be querying data
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    // Query the posts
    $all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results();
    // Loop into all the posts
    foreach($all_blog_posts as $key => $post): 
      $msg .= '<div class = "col-md-12">' . $post->post_title . '</div>';
    endforeach;
```

На сколько я понимаю, мне нужно в `foreach` поместить `include locate_template( 'include/vlog-news.php' );`. Подскажите, как мне правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя цикл `foreach` вам нужно руками сетапить пост, **важный момент аргументом функции должна быть переменная $post**

```
foreach($all_blog_posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    include locate_template( 'include/vlog-news.php' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но вы скорее всего забыли двоеточие поставить

Comment: в моем примере не используется альтернативный синтаксис)

Comment: Не подскажите, почему у меня отображаются не все элементы из цикла? Например, отображается дата поста, а тайтл поста нет, отображается автор, а миниатюра нет. Вывод постов идет функцией из function.php. Если выводить в другом файле темы через WP_Query, тогда все элементы отображаются.

Comment: не совсем представляю как вы это делаете, но возможно вам поможет объявление в начале вашей функции глобальной переменной $post

Comment: Все верно! Спасибо вам большое! )